# Challenge: Can You Point out the Mistake in Here?

Tags: calculus

Find the $p$-discriminant of the differential equation $F(x,y,p)\equiv 4xp^2-(3x-1)^2=0.$(Note: $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$)

We proceed to calculate the $p$-discriminant of $F(x,y,p)=0,$ where $F$ is the function representating the differential equation in the question. So, $F(x,y,p)=4xp^2-(3x-1)^2=0\implies 4xp^2-9x^2-1+6x=0.$

We know that,

The $p$-discriminant which is precisely, the eliminant between :

i.$\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}=0,$

ii.$F(x,y,p)=0.$

So, we get,
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}=\frac{\partial (4xp^2-9x^2-1+6x)}{\partial p}=8xp=0\implies 4xp^2=0$$

and,

$F(x,y,c)=4xp^2-9x^2-1+6x=0.$ Now, we eliminate $p$ as follows:

$$(\frac{\partial F}{\partial c})\frac p2-F(x,y,c)=4xp^2-(4xp^2-9x^2-1+6x)=(3x-1)^2.$$ So, the $p$-discriminant is, $(3x-1)^2=0.$

---

However, the answer given is $x(3x-1)^2.$ I am not sure if I have made any mistake. Any help regarding this, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is this question titled as a "challenge"? Doesn't seem very appropriate to me.

Comment: @IraeVid Haha, that's because up until now, *no one* could answer this, so considering the number of days I posted it, it seems that it's challenging, if not hard.

Comment: Maybe you should start a bounty?